# Odoo - Python | File name too long, when processing images

Tags: python, odoo, python-imaging-library

today I was making some code that will resize a few images that already been uploaded. It is actually a def function and called when the button is pressed on the Odoo web client.

Code:

```
@api.multi
def resize_image(self):
  for record in self:
    Image.open(self.foto1).resize((800, 600),Image.ANTIALIAS).save(self.foto1, quality=100)
```

Error:

```
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/asset/asset.py", line 209, in resize_image
    Image.open(self.foto1).resize((800, 600),Image.ANTIALIAS).save(self.foto1, quality=100)
IOError: [Errno 36] File name too long: '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/7QFKUGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAREcAVoAAxslRxwCAAACAAIcAhkAJkFGLVMgR
```

I can't give all the error file name because it's probably the byte itself...

Answer (score 0):

```
import cStringIO

@api.multi
def resize_image(self):
  for record in self:
    Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(self.foto1.decode('base64'))).resize((800, 600),Image.ANTIALIAS).save(self.foto1, quality=100)
```